# Execute commands in anaconda prompt using IDE console

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt

I'm trying to execute commands in SPyder that will be run on Anaconda propmt.
I tried os, but its open windows cmd but not anaconda prompt.
The commands I want to run are:
"conda activate myenv"- activate enviorment.
"cd C:..." - Change to specific directory.
fmask_sentinel2Stacked.py -o cloud.img --safedir S2B_MSIL1C_20191202T082219_N0208_R121_T36SXA_20191202T101931.SAFE- run Fmask package command.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because i want to use Fmask package, which can be implement only from anaconda prompt

Comment: Have you tried? You should be able to run the commands you shared in the Windows Command Prompt without any issue.